# I have a this error en laravel : Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition.How do I solve this problem?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, migration

** SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key (SQL: create table `loans` (`id_loan` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `book_id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `user_id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `date_vto` date not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci').How do I solve this problem?

**

**Migrations**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id_book');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('amount');
    });
}
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('role');

    });
}
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('loans', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id_loan');
        $table->bigIncrements('book_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigIncrements('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->date('date_vto');

        $table->foreign('book_id')->references('id_book')->on('books')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**Models**
**books**

```
public function loans(){
    return $this->hasMany(Loans::class);
}
```

**Models Loans**

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Books::class, 'book_id', 'id_book');
}
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Users::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

**Models Users**

```
public function loans(){
        return $this->hasMany(Loans::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite self-explanatory:

> ```
>     $table->increments('id_loan');
>     $table->bigIncrements('book_id')->unsigned();
>     $table->bigIncrements('user_id')->unsigned();
> ```

You are adding more than one auto increment data type in your database. What you can do is using the same data type, but not incremented, and for `bigIncrements`, it's `unsignedBigInteger`.

You can clearly see in the [document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-bigIncrements) that:

> The bigIncrements method creates an auto-incrementing UNSIGNED BIGINT
> **(primary key)** equivalent column

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('book_id')->unsigned();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
```

Replace in migration and try again.

Comment: you don't need the extra `unsigned` fluent call since `unsignedBigInteger` is unsigned ... btw

Comment: i have a this error now : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `vuejslaravel5`.`loans` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `loans` add constraint `loans_libro_id_foreign` foreign key (`book_id`) references `books` (`id_book`) on delete cascade)